# How to do "hg backout X" in Git?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, backout

I have to use Git and want to undo one commit that was some commits before the tip. In Hg it's `hg backout`. What's the analog command in Git?

(I duckduckwent before posting this and dont's see an analog command.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you need git revert :) Alternatively, if you want to remove all evidence that that commit ever happened, you could do a git rebase to get rid of it. But be careful if you've already published that commit somewhere visible as you can create problems for other people.

Here's a link talking about revert:

http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/03/16/rolling-back-changes-with-revert.html

Alternatively, just Google for the manual documentation.

Comment: There is an alternative to `git rebase` if you want to totally get rid of n commits from the head: `git reset --hard HEAD~n`

Comment: True, and git reset --hard is also more generally useful, e.g. for undoing a rebase gone bad. The question here does talk about a commit before the head in this case though.

Answer (score 13):

To revert some specific commits you can use:

```
git revert <commit_hash>
```

This will add a new commit that reverts `commit_hash` commit.

If you want to erase a specific commit by rewriting history,
you can do:

```
git rebase -i <commit_hash>^
```

This will open an editor. Just delete the line that contains the
`commit_hash` you want to erase, save the file and quit the editor.
The rebase will erase the `commit_hash` commit.

Answer (score 3):

There is the official Git and Hg equivalent commands maintained here:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/GitConcepts#Command_equivalence_table

And the equivalent for `hg backout` is `git revert`

Comment: This is a useful table.  However, when using it as a reference, keep in mind that it "refers to Mercurial v1.8 and Git v1.7.4".